# Updating whole Database in DynamoDB with FilterExpression and ExclusiveStartKey

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have a database in AWS DynamoDB and want to add a field to all items　where it's currently undefined. I was wondering what the best way would be to go about that. I am considering two options:

1. use scan with filter expression `attribute_not_exists(myNewField)` and repeat until it returns no results anymore
2. use scan without filter, check logic later and iterate over all items with `ExclusiveStartKey`

My question is which one of these would be better or if either could cause problems

The original reason I wanted to ask this question to ask if I could use filter expression `attribute_not_exists(myNewField)`, then add `myNewField` with an update expression and if I then use `ExclusiveStartKey` to get the next batch (still with `attribute_not_exists(myNewField)`) will it give me the correct next batch, will it start over or will there be a some items skipped. Or if someone could share a source to read about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the LastEvaluatedKey to determine how far you've scanned through the table, it's a pointer to the last item in the page you returned.

When you set that as the ExclusiveStartKey then you pick up from where the last item read, exclusive of that item.

What that means is that either option is the same, there is no difference in cost or performance and both will work. However, applying the filter on DynamoDB simplifies your client side code as DynamoDB is responsible for applying the filter logic.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the expensive part of this is goinG to be the update operations for which there is no way around the fact that you have to make one UpdateItem request for every item in the table.

That is if you really need to add the field to every item. Consider if there is a way to only add the field to a small number of items. That would save a lot.

Another option may be to export your table to S3 - make the updates offline and reimport as a new table, dropping the old one. This could really pay off is you have a very large table and you can afford to make it readonly while you update.